# getting the exception class name in python?

Tags: python, exception

I want to generate a string in an exception handler that contains the name of the exception, and any arguments passed...oretty much the final output that one gets with Traceback.

For example, if `raise bar.FnordError("message")` is called, in the exception handler, I want to produce the string: `"bar.FnordError: message"`

I want it to work for built in exceptions, as well as exceptions in the current and other modules.  This is what I came up with, but it doesn't seem very pythonic.

```
def this_is_lame(err):
    if type(err).__module__ in ['__main__', 'builtins']:
        return "{}: {}".format(type(err).__name__, err)
    else:
        return "{}.{}: {}".format(type(err).__module__, type(err).__name__, err)
```

I've dug through the BaseException C code in python, and the Traceback standard library. I seem to be missing the correct "nice" accessor.

Is `BaseException.__format__` documented anywhere?  Are there escapes for it?

I've played around in the interpreter and nothing quite gives me what I want.

```
import sys
import traceback

import bar

try:
    raise bar.FnordError("message")
except Exception as err:
    print(type(err))
    print(repr(err))
    print(type(err).__module__)
    print(type(err).__name__)
    print(err)
    print("this is what I want: '{}'".format(this_is_lame(err)))

print()

try:
    raise ValueError("message")
except Exception as err:
    print(type(err))
    print(repr(err))
    print(type(err).__module__)
    print(type(err).__name__)
    print("this is what I want: '{}'".format(this_is_lame(err)))
```

which produces:

```
$ python foo.py
<class 'bar.FnordError'>
FnordError('message',)
bar
FnordError
message
this is what I want: 'bar.FnordError: message'

<class 'ValueError'>
ValueError('message',)
builtins
ValueError
this is what I want: 'ValueError: message'
```

Comment: I think your this_is_lame_too function is actually pretty nifty. Useful for figuring out someone's code. Seems good to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no "nice" accessor. Python itself does something pretty similar to what you're doing in the default `sys.excepthook`, although exceptions defined in `__main__` print as `__main__.WhateverException`.

If you want to see how Python itself does it, on Python 2, the check happens in [`PyErr_Display`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#l1276), which checks `strcmp(modstr, "exceptions")`:

```
moduleName = PyObject_GetAttrString(exception, "__module__");
if (moduleName == NULL)
    err = PyFile_WriteString("<unknown>", f);
else {
    char* modstr = PyString_AsString(moduleName);
    if (modstr && strcmp(modstr, "exceptions"))
    {
        err = PyFile_WriteString(modstr, f);
        err += PyFile_WriteString(".", f);
    }
    Py_DECREF(moduleName);
}
```

On Python 3, [`print_exception`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/pythonrun.c#l743) checks `_PyUnicode_CompareWithId(moduleName, &PyId_builtins)`.

```
moduleName = _PyObject_GetAttrId(type, &PyId___module__);
if (moduleName == NULL || !PyUnicode_Check(moduleName))
{
    Py_XDECREF(moduleName);
    err = PyFile_WriteString("<unknown>", f);
}
else {
    if (_PyUnicode_CompareWithId(moduleName, &PyId_builtins) != 0)
    {
        err = PyFile_WriteObject(moduleName, f, Py_PRINT_RAW);
        err += PyFile_WriteString(".", f);
    }
    Py_DECREF(moduleName);
}
```

Comment: What is `PyId_builtins`? Where is this defined?

Comment: There is a macro in `Python.h`: `_Py_IDENTIFIER(foo)` which initialises a structure named `PyId_foo` containing the string `"foo"`. Hence we see variables such as `PyId_builtins`/`PyId___builtins__`.