# local variable 'responsedata' referenced before assignment (using requests library)

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
   def getdata2(self, page, data, apifolder, additional):
    def _handle_exception(e,tries,n,page,thread_name):
        print ("I was called on thread {1} page {0}".format(page,thread_name))
        if n == tries - 1:
            print ("page {0} could not be imported. Max retried reached.".format(page))
            print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
            os._exit(1)  # One thread max retried - close all threads and exit the process. Airflow will retry the script.

    tries = 10
    value_limit = self.config.keros_page_limit  # limit of records allowed per page
    thread_name = threading.current_thread().getName()
    for n in range(tries):
        try:
            value_offset = page * value_limit
            datarALL = []
            url = 'http://...&offset={0}&limit={1}{3}'.format(
                value_offset, value_limit, apifolder, additional)
            print ("{3} Thread: {4} Generate page: #{0} run #{1} with URL: {2}".format(page, n, url,str(datetime.now()),thread_name))
            responsedata = requests.get(url, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False, timeout=120)
            responsedata.raise_for_status()
            if responsedata.status_code == 200:  # 200 for successful call
                responsedata = responsedata.text
                jsondata = json.loads(responsedata)
                if "results" in jsondata:
                    if jsondata["results"]:
                        datarALL.extend(jsondata["results"])
                        break

        except UnboundLocalError as e:
            print ("Thread {3} page #{0} run #{1} failed. Msg: {2}. Retry.".format(page, n, sys.exc_info()[0], thread_name))
            _handle_exception(e, tries, n, page, thread_name)
            continue

        except (ConnectionResetError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError, requests.exceptions.Timeout) as e:
            print ("Thread {3} page #{0} run #{1} failed. Msg: {2}. Retry.".format(page, n, sys.exc_info()[0], thread_name))
            _handle_exception(e, tries, n, page, thread_name)
            continue


        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print ("Thread {5} page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0], thread_name))
            _handle_exception(e, tries, n, page, thread_name)
            continue

    time.sleep( 10 )
    print ("{2} Thread: {3} page {0} finished. Length is {1}".format(page,len(datarALL),str(datetime.now()),thread_name))
    return datarALL
```

The `getdata2` function is called from this function using threads:

```
def kData(self, data, auth_token, apifolder, additional_parameter_key=None, additional_parameter_value=None):

    try:
        self.hed = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth_token, 'Accept': 'application/json'}
        additional = ''
        if additional_parameter_key is not None and additional_parameter_value is not None:
            additional = '&{0}={1}'.format(additional_parameter_key, additional_parameter_value)
        urlApi = 'http://...offset=0&limit=1{1}'.format(
            apifolder, additional)
        responsefirst = requests.get(urlApi, data=data, headers=self.hed, verify=False)
        if responsefirst.ok:
            num_of_records = int(math.ceil(responsefirst.json()['total']))
            if num_of_records == 0:
                print ("No new records to import.")
                return None
            value_limit = 1000  # Number of records per page.
            num_of_pages = int(math.ceil(num_of_records / value_limit))
            num_of_pages = 10
            print ("num of records to import is {0}".format(num_of_records))
            print ("num of pages to import is {0}".format(num_of_pages))
            pages = [i for i in range(0, num_of_pages)]
            datarALL = []
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
                futh = [(executor.submit(self.getdata2, page, data, apifolder, additional)) for page in pages]
                for data in as_completed(futh):
                    datarALL.extend(data.result())
            print ("Finished generateing data.")
            return datarALL
        else:
            print (responsefirst)
            return None

    except UnboundLocalError as e:
        print (str(e))
        sys.exit(1)

    except Exception as e:
        print ("hi")
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        print (str(e))
        sys.exit(1)
```

This code create 4 workers and generate pages to import data.
if a thread (page) encounter an error it should retry. after 10 attempts if it's still unsuccessful the code exits.

However I'm encountering another behavior:

```
num of records to import is 22670
num of pages to import is 10
2018-09-16 07:30:23.794804 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #0 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=0&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:30:23.796471 Thread: Thread-2 Generate page: #1 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=1000&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:30:23.798062 Thread: Thread-3 Generate page: #2 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=2000&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:30:23.799695 Thread: Thread-4 Generate page: #3 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=3000&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:31:32.191233 Thread: Thread-2 Generate page: #4 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=4000&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:31:41.620356 Thread: Thread-1 page 0 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-16 07:31:41.863625 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #5 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=5000&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:32:31.686173 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #6 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=6000&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:32:41.656820 Thread: Thread-2 page 4 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-16 07:32:41.730020 Thread: Thread-2 Generate page: #7 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=7000&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:33:31.371733 Thread: Thread-1 page 6 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-16 07:33:31.372399 Thread: Thread-1 Generate page: #8 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=8000&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:33:31.755262 Thread: Thread-3 Generate page: #9 run #0 with URL: http://...&offset=9000&limit=1000
2018-09-16 07:33:41.404450 Thread: Thread-2 page 7 finished. Length is 1000
2018-09-16 07:34:23.214937 Thread: Thread-3 page 9 finished. Length is 1000
local variable 'responsedata' referenced before assignment
Command exited with return code 1
```

`Thread-3` never reported finishing for `page 2` nor it reported retry.
I don't understand what is the problem.

I'm pretty sure that it's related to the `responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason` in my `requests.exceptions.RequestException`. If so - how can I separate my prints to exceptions which can print this variables and exceptions that can not. It's important for me to know why the thread retried.

To explain better what I'm asking:
I want to seperate the exceptions to two:
exceptions which `responsedata.raise_for_status()` will set the `responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason` and exceptions that will not.
How can I do that? The request library does not specify it.

**EDIT:**

My question is which exceptions I need to list here:

```
except (Exceptions that **can not use**  raise_for_status ) as e:
    print ("Thread {3} page #{0} run #{1} failed. Msg: {2}. Retry.".format(page, n, sys.exc_info()[0], thread_name))
    continue

except (Exceptions that **can use**  raise_for_status ) as e:
    print ("Thread {5} page #{0} run #{1} failed. Returned status code {2}. Reason: {3}. Msg: {4}. Retry.".format(page, n, responsedata.status_code, responsedata.reason, sys.exc_info()[0], thread_name))
    _handle_exception(e, tries, n, page, thread_name)
    continue
```

Comment: If the line `responsedata = requests.get(...)` throws an exception, then the variable `responsedata` isn't defined in the `except` block. Now that you know that, please reduce your code to a [mcve].

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm aware of that. the `responsedata.raise_for_status()` suppose to set these variables but apparently in some cases it does not. I'm asking here which exceptions of request I can use the responsedata and for which I can't

Comment: `responsedata.raise_for_status()` does not set any variables. If the call to `requests.get(...)` throws an exception, then `responsedata` is never assigned to a value and `responsedata.raise_for_status()` is never executed.

Comment: @Aran-Fey again. I understand that. I want to make two separated exceptions. Thous that will handle the requests.get(...) and thous that will handle the responsedata.raise_for_status(). The problem is that there is no list of execptions for each. This is why I'm asking here.

Comment: @Aran-Fey see edit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting the exception class name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921759/getting-the-exception-class-name-in-python)

Comment: @stovfl would you mind to explain how this is relevant?

Comment: @stovfl This is not what I asked here. Check what I wrote under "EDIT:"

Comment: @stovfl And your referred answer is related to the request package how? The request package has exceptions of requests and of urllib3, Some are overwritten and some are not. I don't think you read my whole issue.

Comment: @stovfl I am but still requests catches some of urlib3 exepction and raise them as request exceptions. None of the docs in the lib explains how to solve this. If you have a solution I'll be happy to hear

Comment: Are you aware of this: [module-urllib3.exceptions](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/index.html#module-urllib3.exceptions)

Comment: Check in this line of code `responsedata = requests.get(...`, if you allways get `responsedata` object.